# Sending a jQuery POST to a Django View

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, csrf

I am sending a POST request via `$.ajax()` to a Django view from a page that is on HTTP - I used the AJAX snippet for CSRF provided [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax). I can view the csrftoken cookie as `Secure` in Firebug; I suppose this is why the the `X-Csrftoken` header for the POST request is being sent as `null`.

Is there any way I can actually access this cookie's value? I am currently bypassing the 403 error (because of the `POST` being sent with a null CSRF token header) by adding `@csrf_exempt` to my view - but would like a proper CSRF method in place.

**UPDATE FOR CLARITY:** I am *not* submitting this data via forms. I am simply sending the POST when a javascript file (containing the AJAX call) is loaded on the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I do for getting a proper csrf solution in place is this:

include my `{% csrf_token %}` in a place it makes sense.

```
var csrfToken = $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();
$.ajax({
    url: $form.attr('action'),
    type: 'POST',
    data: postData,
    csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrfToken,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) { }
});
```

I have struggled to get this working:

```
var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken');
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
    }
});
```

But so far the first solution has proven to be the one that works best.

Comment: In your example, `csrfmiddlewaretoken` is a hidden field in a form. However, in my case, I'm sending this POST request on page load (called as soon as the JS containing the `$.ajax()` is loaded) - i.e. there is no form. What do I do in my case?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then you would have to render a csrf_token in the view "before" and have it sent with the "GET" request. OR if this is impossible for you, you could do with a Middleware that "injects" the csrf_token in your request.

Comment: Yes, the `csrf_token` is already available. I just tried adding `csrfmiddlewaretoken` to the AJAX call as shown in your first example, and it works! Is this documented?

Comment: @GPX Yeah, its documented somewhat. Bullet #2 at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-it-works covers it but not how to include it in the ajax for jquery calls like I do.